# Converting std::string to LPCSTR

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a program which allows the user to create a folder. The user enters the folder name and that input gets inserted into the CreateDirectory function. However it will not compile. The folder is created in C:\test\ where the subfolder name is users input. Has anyone any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string input = "";
    string address = "C:\\test\\";
    string total = input+address;
    cout << "Please the name of the folder:\n>";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;
    cout << "Path name is " << address+input << endl << endl;
    CreateDirectory(total,NULL); 
    //system("mkdir " + input); //Same error when I use mkdir

    return 0;
}
```

I receive this error from the compiler.

> C:\C++\file\main.cpp|17|error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string
>   {aka    std::__cxx11::basic_string}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const
>   char*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL CreateDirectoryA(LPCSTR,
>   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)'|

---Update---
Thanks for the replies, much appreciated. I used the c_str() fix. Code is working now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string input1 = "C:\\test\\";
string input2 = "";
cout << "Please enter the name of the folder:\n>";
getline(cin, input2);
string total = input1+input2;
CreateDirectory(total.c_str(),NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CreateDirectory(total.c_str(),NULL);`, the API is not aware of C+ strings.

Comment: ^^^ That. Since it doesn't compile, the name of the directory is not relevant btw.

Comment: You are computing the total **BEFORE** the `getline`. So you are just using the initial value of total (which is an empty string). You print `address+input` but you use `total` to create the Folder.

Comment: Also your compilation error is because `CreateDirectory` expects a char* instead of a string. just define your total as char*

Comment: @Sembei but then he'd have to allocate it and combine the two std::strings himself. It's going to be easier to use `.c_str()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reponses.